# 15 books, 15 shelves, each book after first has to be next to an existing one

Tags: combinatorics

There are 15 books, 15 partitions on a shelf, each book after first has to be next to an existing one. Books are numbered and are put onto the shelf in order (1,2,3,...,15). One partition should contain exactly one book. How many ways are there to put books on the shelf?
I have tried the following solutions, but they are not correct:

1. 15 + $2^{13}$ + 1  (Initially 15 places to put books, then 2 places for next 13 books, and only one place for last book).
2. 15 * $2^{13}$ + 1
   Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The rules are not clear.  If each book  (other than the first) must be placed next to an already placed book, then surely all the books must be on the same shelf as the first book.  Otherwise, what does that condition mean?   And what does "one shelf should contain exactly one book" mean?  Should each shelf have exactly one?  Exactly one shelf should have exactly one?  At least one shelf should have exactly one?

Comment: Should add  we can't tell you where you are going wrong since you give no explanation of how you came up with those values.

Comment: @lulu My apologies, confused "shelf" with "partition"

Comment: Ok, but then it is not always true that a book (after the first) has two options.  If, say, the first book is in the first partition then book $2$ (and all subsequent books) can only go in one partition each.

Comment: I suggest:  solve the problem for smaller $n$ (here $n=15$).  Good practice, if nothing else, and perhaps a useful pattern will emerge.

Comment: @lulu thank you for the hint, I assumed that a book after the one on the edge can be but on the slot on the opposite edge, hence my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put book $1$ into partition $k$, then there are $14$ books left, $k-1$ of which will end up to the left of book $1$, and $15-k$ will end up to the right.

To choose the $k-1$ books, use the binomial coefficient $\binom{14}{k-1}$, and to get the
answer, sum over all $k$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{15} \binom{14}{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{14} \binom{14}{k} = 2^{14}$$

Answer (score 1):

First imagine a longer shelf with $29$ spots. Put book 1 in the middle slot (so all the books would fit to left of book 1 or all would fit to the right of book 1. Now place book 2 either just to the left or just to the right of book 1. Next place book 3 just left or just right of the block of already placed books. Continue doing this for books 4, 5,...,15. For each book after the first you have two choices: left of the previous books or right of the previous books. So there are $2^{14}$ ways to arrange the books.

Finally move the books onto the shelf of $15$ spaces, preserving their relative order.